# statically testing the type of an STL iterator forward/bidirectional/random access?

Tags: c++11

Is there a way to test statically the type of an iterator and have a template which depends on it execute different but code depending on the type(since algorithm choice changes)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) to get the category of the iterator. Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<
        std::iterator_traits<decltype(v.begin())>::iterator_category,
        std::random_access_iterator_tag>);          
}
```

You can then overload on the tag types to provide static dispatch:

```
void foo(std::random_access_iterator_tag); // (0)
void foo(std::bidirectional_iterator_tag); // (1)

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::list<int> v;
    foo(std::iterator_traits<decltype(v.begin())>::iterator_category{}); // calls 0
    foo(std::iterator_traits<decltype(l.begin())>::iterator_category{}); // calls 1
}
```

Comment: thanks. That half answers the question. Is there a good way to execute different code depending on the result?

Comment: @C.Cheng: you can simply provide multiple overloads that take different category tag types. Google will be helpful here, as this is a relatively common question.